# Constant for a multi-dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to create a multi-dimensional array, the size of which the user will supply.

So far I have this:

```
int definedgroups; // for number of groups needed

cout << "Enter the Number of Groups you require: " << endl;
cin >> definedgroups;
const int definedgroups = definedgroups;

int User_Groups [definedgroups] [4];
```

I believe the array needs constant values, so i tried assigning my variable as a constant but still no luck.

Comment: By "constant values" do you mean values in the array that cannot be changed?

Comment: yes but at the start i want it to be defined by the user

Answer (score 3):

In C++, **static** arrays, that is, those defined like this:

```
foo arrayStatic[bar];
```

require `bar` to be a constant integer. In other words, the programmer needs to know its value beforehand.

Whenever `bar` is unknown, a **dynamic** array could be used instead. They're defined like this:

```
foo* arrayDynamic;
arrayDynamic = new foo[bar];
```

Here, `bar` could be an integer variable.

Don't forget that dynamic memory must be deallocated eventually. So, in this case, we can deallocate `arrayDynamic` like this:

```
delete [] arrayDynamic;
```

A two-dimensional dynamic array is defined analogously:

```
foo** arrayDynamic2D;
arrayDynamic2D = new foo*[bar];
for (int i = 0; i < bar; i++)
   arrayDynamic2D[i] = new foo[baz];
```

and deallocated in a similar fashion:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bar; i++)
   delete [] arrayDynamic2D[i];
delete [] arrayDynamic2D;
```

Static memory is allocated in the **stack** whereas dynamic memory is allocated in the **heap**.

Comment: Can we do `new foo[bar]` *before* we know what `bar`s value is?? I'm just trying to understand why we need to use dynamic memory allocation. Is it for this reason?

Comment: Clearly, `bar` needs to be initialized by the programmer or the user before it can be used in `new foo[bar]`. It doesn't have to be of type `const int`, however.

Comment: But I'm still not getting why we need to use dynamic memory allocation??

Comment: In C++, if you want to use an **array** to store your data and whose dimensions are unknown before program execution, you **need** to use dynamic memory allocation because, otherwise, the compiler would have no idea how much memory to allocate in the stack for its static counterpart.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do it in C++ using static arrays. Use `std::vector` in a hierarchical way (i.e. vectors of vectors) to implement a multi-dimensional array easily (though not necessarily very efficiently).

E.g.

`std::vector<std::vector<double> > array(nrows, std::vector<double>(ncols));`

creates a `nrows` x `ncols` matrix.

Comment: `std::vector<std::array<int, 4> >` would be better in this case

Answer (score 0):

You need dynamic memory allocation using `new`:

```
int **User_Groups = new int*[definedgroups];
//Allocate memory for 2nd dimension
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    User_Groups[i] = new int[4];
```

Comment: Because in order to specify the size of the array at runtime you need to allocate memory on the heap. You cannot do that on the stack.